# VS Code auto formatting with prettier

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

Is it possible to auto format on VS Code in directory whose root doesn't have prettier config?

```
- root <-  current directory on VS Code
 - app
  - src <- Do i have to be here to run auto formatting??
   - .prettierrc
   - package.json
   - file1
```

I cannot run prettier in root directory. Do I have to be in the directory which has `prettierrc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include a proper `.prettierrc` file in the root directory, as the [docs about Prettier Configuration File](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html) says:

> The configuration file will be resolved starting from the location of the file being formatted, and searching up the file tree until a config file is (or isn’t) found.
>
> Prettier intentionally doesn’t support any kind of global configuration. This is to make sure that when a project is copied to another computer, Prettier’s behavior stays the same. Otherwise, Prettier wouldn’t be able to guarantee that everybody in a team gets the same consistent results.

```
root
├── app
│   ├── file4
│   ├── public
│   │   └── file5
│   └── src
│       ├── file1
│       ├── package.json
│       └── .prettierrc
├── file2
├── file3
└── .prettierrc
```

If you have a directory structure like above, the files under `root/app/src/` (`file1`, `package.json` and `root/app/src/.prettierrc`) will be formatted according to `root/app/src/.prettierrc` config file, and other files under `root/` or its subdirectories (`file2`, `file3`, `root/.prettierrc`, `file4`, and `file5`) will be formatted according to `root/.prettierrc` config file.

---

Or you can [configure default options of Prettier for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode#configuring-default-options):

> **Configuring Default Options**
>
> Some users may not wish to create a new Prettier config for every project or use the VS Code settings. Because Prettier searches recursively up the file path, you can place a global prettier config at `~/.prettierrc` to be used as a fallback.
>
> You can also use the setting [`prettier.configPath`](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#prettierconfigpath) to provide a global configuration. However, be careful, if this is set this value will always be used and local configuration files will be ignored.